# What's the order of threads in Java thread dump?

Tags: java, multithreading, stack

What defines the order of threads in a thread dump?

When we take a thread dump in java. I am trying to make sense of behavior a java program. (jdk8)

Thread dump is taken using `jdk\bin\jstack` command.

## Small Example:

> 2019-06-19 09:37:56
>
> Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.161-b12 mixed
>   mode):
>
> "thread_xyz" #8317 prio=5
>
> trace...xyz
>
> "thread_abc" #8316 prio=5
>
> trace...abc

I want to understand what decides the order of output `thread_abc` after thread `thread_xyz`  in the thread dump.

Comment: I'm curious why the order is important to you? What are you trying to find in the thread dump?

Comment: Thank yours for the edits. I am trying to compare 2 thread dumps, good state of a process vs bad state. I am guessing the busiest thread comes on top, but not sure.

Answer (score 1):

> What defines the order of threads in a thread dump?

I suspect that the answer to this question depends highly on the JDK version and maybe even the OS implementation.

Looking at `java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.141` and `java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131` versions under Linux, it looks like the stack trace is ordered by the thread-id in reverse order.

```
"foo2" #11 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f595010c800 ...
"foo" #10 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f595010b000 ...
"Service Thread" #9 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f59500e5000 ...
"C1 CompilerThread3" #8 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f59500d8000 ...
"C2 CompilerThread2" #7 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f59500d6000 ...
"C2 CompilerThread1" #6 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f59500d4000 ...
"C2 CompilerThread0" #5 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f59500c6800 ...
"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f59500c4800 ...
"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f595009b000 ...
"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5950096800 ...
"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5950008000 ...
"VM Thread" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f595008c800 ...
"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f595001d800 ...
"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f595001f000 ...
...
"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f59500e8000 ...
```

Notice that there are a number of "internal" threads which seem not to have numbers at all that are in the list.

Also, in these versions of java, the thread-id is a synchronized long++ done in the thread constructor.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. I found some more analysis here https://github.com/huy/hotspot_jvm_notes/blob/master/jstack-how-it-works.md

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare thread dumps (or even just see what's going on in it), the easiest way is to create the dump and use a free online analyzer like [fastthread.io](https://fastthread.io) or [jstack.view](https://jstack.review). The way they visualize it is normally helpful in finding hotspots.

Comment: Thank you. These were very useful. esp to compare the diff. But in my case, the thread dumps were almost identical except for the order.